# Alternative for deprecated PHP function: kd_mfi_get_featured_image_id

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Hello I have used this wp function kd_mfi_get_featured_image_id that is deprecated. But in error log actually I have a big amount of rows due to this function and I think that affect on performances too.

It is also used by my theme that is one of the most used (Avada).

So I wanna ask you an alternative for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `kd_mfi_get_featured_image_id` function has been deprecated since
>   Avada 5.2.0. Please use `fusion_get_featured_image_id` instead.

Taken from [here](https://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226/comments?page=1383)

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you so much